# Upload de foto com input camera HTML5 e PHP

Tags: php, html5

estou utilizando o novo método de upload de fotos onde se usar do celular ele abre a câmera e se usar de um computador ele abre os arquivos... porém se tento realizar o upload da foto pelo celular ele simplesmente não acontece, diferente de se eu fizer um upload pelo computador, ele faz normalmente, alguém poderia me ajudar?

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" name="foto" accept="image/*" capture>
```

**PHP**

```
$foto = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$foto_nome = Limpar($nome_vinho).'-'.$safra.'-'.$vinicola;
$local = "assets/uploads/vinhos/";
$extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto']['name'],-4));
$final = $local.$foto_nome.'.'.$extensao;

move_uploaded_file($foto, $final);
```